# Applying for a Austria Study visa with a prior refusal from the UK?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, study, austria

I am from Pakistan. I have had a refusal for false information due to a bank statement provided, which the officer mentioned 'is non-genuine' for study visa from the UK in December, 2022.

I am thinking of applying to Austria for study visa... Will this past refusal have an effect on my application for Austria visa?

Comment: Do you have a genuine bank statement to provide?

Answer (score 1):

The National (*D*) visa [form](https://www.bmeia.gv.at/fileadmin/user_upload/Zentrale/Reise_Aufenthalt/Einreise_und_Aufenthalt/Form_D_1_-_Antragsformular_nationales_Visum.doc) from Austria doesn't ask you about refusals or anything of the likes

**Now**, don't assume they won't know about it, it is perfectly possible (although unlikely) that they know about the refusal and will act accordingly